# I can't display a name from.txt file with a line number in the console

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a Names.txt file I created with 4 names,bill,dave,mike, andjim

I can enter the file name and I can enter the name to search, for example dave above and then the console should return "dave appears on line 2 of Names.txt". Instead it returns "dave does not exist", which would be correct if it is not one of the four names. What mistake I am making in my while loop below?

```
public class names {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String friendName;    // Friend's name      

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get the filename.
        System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Open the file.
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        // Get the name of a friend.
        System.out.print("Enter name to search: ");
        friendName = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        int lineNumber = 1;         

        while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            if ("friendName".equals(inputFile.nextLine().trim())) {
                // found
                String line = inputFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println("friendName" + " appears on line " + lineNumber + " of Names.txt");
                lineNumber++; 
                //break;
            } else {
                // not found
                System.out.println(friendName + " does not exist. ");
                break;
            }
        }

        // Close the file.
        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are comparing a string `"friendName"` instead of String variable friendName.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from `friendName` and use the actual variable which you read in from the file:

```
int lineNumber = 1;
booelan found = false;

while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String nextLine = inputFile.nextLine().trim();
    if (friendName.equals(nextLine)) {
        // found
        found = true;
        break;        // name is found, no point in searching any further
    }

    lineNumber++;     // always increment the line number
}

if (found) {
    System.out.println(friendName + " appears on line " + lineNumber + " of Names.txt");
}
else {
    System.out.println(friendName + " does not exist. ");
}
```

I also changed the way you use your `Scanner`.  In your original code, you were calling `Scanner.nextLine()` twice in the case of a match with the friend name.  This would cause the scanner to advance *two* lines which is not what you want.

Comment: @Jackwhyski Please review the answers given, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Names
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        String friendName;    // Friend's name

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get the filename.
        System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Open the file.
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        // Get the name of a friend.
        System.out.print("Enter name to search: ");
        friendName = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        int lineNumber = 0;
        Boolean isFound = false;
        while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
            lineNumber++;
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            if(line.trim().contains(friendName)){
                System.out.println(friendName + " appears on line " + lineNumber + " of Names.txt");
            }
        }
        if(!isFound){
            System.out.println("given friend name "+friendName+" not exists in the file");
        }
        // Close the file.
        inputFile.close();
    } }
```

Comment: Addressed the issues exists in the program that you have provided, try now with the sample program posted above.

Comment: corrected the flaw in the counter logic .. and one observation is  current program searches the names is case-sensitive.